# Help with "Exec=..." line for .desktop launcher - command works only in terminal

Tags: bash, launcher, .desktop

I want to add another context menu option to my Thunderbird launcher in Unity. However, it does not work. The additional action appears in the launcher's context menu, and when I click it the cursor changes to the "waiting circle" for a few seconds but then nothing happens. If I run the script in a terminal, it works like a charm.
**What do I have to change to run those needed commands from the launcher context menu?**

The commands I need to run are outsourced to a bash script file, so the Exec-line is:

```
Exec=/bin/bash -c "/home/bytecommander/bin/thunderbird-win.sh"
```

Content of `/home/bytecommander/bin/thunderbird-win.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash

# Launches Thunderbird after mounting the Windows partition with that profile.
# Both mount commands as root are set in the sudoers file to not ask for passwords.

sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/windows
thunderbird -p windows
sudo umount /dev/sda2
```

Shortened content of `/usr/share/applications/thunderbird.desktop` (without translations):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Thunderbird Mail
Comment=Send and receive mail with Thunderbird
GenericName=Mail Client
Keywords=Email;E-mail;Newsgroup;Feed;RSS
Exec=thunderbird %u
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=thunderbird
Categories=Application;Network;Email;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/mailto;application/x-xpinstall;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=Compose;Contacts;LoadWindowsProfile

[Desktop Action Compose]
Name=Compose New Message
Exec=thunderbird -compose
OnlyShowIn=Messaging Menu;Unity;

[Desktop Action Contacts]
Name=Contacts
Exec=thunderbird -addressbook
OnlyShowIn=Messaging Menu;Unity;

[Desktop Action LoadWindowsProfile]
Name=Run with Windows profile
Exec=/bin/bash -c "/home/bytecommander/bin/thunderbird-win.sh"
OnlyShowIn=Messaging Menu;Unity;
```

Comment: Do you have a password for sudo?

Comment: @Bruni I added those two mount commands to my `sudoers` file with `NOPASSWD`, so I don't get prompted for them. This works, as I can run the script in a terminal where I did not run any `sudo` before.

Comment: `Exec=thunderbird-win.sh`

Comment: @doug Does not work. That way I don't even get the wait-cursor. Now happens less than nothing.

Comment: Is the script executable?  And in case it isn't in your path, use `Exec=/home/bytecommander/bin/thunderbird-win.sh`

Comment: @MartinThornton It is executable (and lets run itself from the terminal just fine), but it does not work with the full path either...

Comment: Can it be that one of those commands inside the script causes the problems? E.g. the `sudo` that breaks it although NOPASSWD is set in the sudoers file? Or might it be that .desktop files can't run bash scripts?

Comment: @ByteCommander, yes, sudo might be configured to require a terminal. You can use `gksudo` or `kdesudo` instead.

Comment: Just for now, add the line `cat` to the end of the script, then try `Exec=xterm -e /home/bytecommander/bin/thunderbird-win.sh`  Do you get an xterm?  Any errors shown in it?

Comment: @MartinThornton I did as you told. An empty xterm showed up for half a second and then vanished again, while some seconds later I got a crash report of `bamfdaemon` - no idea what this is responsible for or whether it is related... But now from the second attempt on, I don't even see the xterm flashing up any more.

Comment: Have you tried adding `Terminal=true` to see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel both sorry and kind of embarrassed to tell you that the issue went away...

The whole reason for that nothing happened if started from the .desktop launcher was a typo in the script path, so that the `Exec=...` line pointed to a non-existent file.

I can only apologize to those who spent any of their time into this issue.

Comment: If you want, feel free to close this question as off-topic because it is not reproducible and went away...

Comment: A good example for "Check twice" :P =) +1

Comment: Don't worry, I spent many hours fixing non-existent problems of my own, caused by typos :) glad it works.